# loadImageFailed() trigger error when using ngx-image-cropper with ngx-bootstrap-modal

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-image-cropper

Notice some intermittent load failure when opening up the ngx-bootstrap-modal to load the ngx-image-cropper. Did some try and error, I've noticed that as long as I open the modal before loadImageFailed() triggered. The cropper will load and everything seems to work fine. Is it got to do with not rendering to the DOM?

I can't find the cause of it though, or am I missing something?

Hope to get some light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is how the modal looks like:

```
<!-- EDIT MODAL -->
<article bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="dialog-sizes-name1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form (ngSubmit)="instructorService.updateCover(instructor.id)">
                <section class="modal-header">
                    <h4 id="dialog-sizes-name1" class="modal-title pull-left">EDIT BANNER</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </section>
                <section class="modal-body">
                    <cropper></cropper>
                </section>
                <section class="modal-footer d-flex bd-highlight">
                    <div class="mr-auto p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <input class="overflow-x" type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" hidden #browser>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-pri" (click)="browser.click()"><b>BROWSE</b></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sec btn-block"
                            (click)="lgModal.hide()"><b>CANCEL</b></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block px-4"
                            (click)="lgModal.hide()"><b>SAVE</b></button>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve it by hooking it up to the lazy-loading component method. But I think that this might just be a workaround. But hey, While waiting for someone else to shine some light, this might just be of help to any of you to pass by.

For how to lazy-load a component. I found this great article by Netanel Basal.

https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a

Cheers~